# Could not load compiled classes for script 'C:\src\flutter\packages\flutter_tools\gradle\flutter.gradle' from cache

Tags: android, flutter, gradle

I am facing this issue when I am compiling my Flutter application
I have recently updated to Flutter 2.0 and after that i am facing this problem on newly created project under 2.0 version
Here is my **flutter doctor -v**

```
[√] Flutter (Channel stable, 2.0.6, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.18363.1500], locale en-IN)
    • Flutter version 2.0.6 at C:\src\flutter
    • Framework revision 1d9032c7e1 (13 days ago), 2021-04-29 17:37:58 -0700
    • Engine revision 05e680e202
    • Dart version 2.12.3

[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 30.0.3)
    • Android SDK at C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Android\sdk
    • Platform android-30, build-tools 30.0.3
    • Java binary at: C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre\bin\java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.8+10-b944.6842174)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[√] Chrome - develop for the web
    • Chrome at C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe

[√] Android Studio (version 3.3)
    • Android Studio at C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio
    • Flutter plugin version 34.0.1
    • Dart plugin version 182.5215
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.8+10-b944.6842174)

[√] VS Code (version 1.56.1)
    • VS Code at C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code
    • Flutter extension version 3.22.0

[√] Connected device (3 available)
    • Redmi Note 8 Pro (mobile) • vwnveij7hqwcrwu8 • android-arm64  • Android 10 (API 29)
    • Chrome (web)              • chrome           • web-javascript • Google Chrome 90.0.4430.212
    • Edge (web)                • edge             • web-javascript • Microsoft Edge 89.0.774.68

• No issues found!
```

Comment: found any solution please?